# how to structure this SQL into a redis database

Tags: ruby, database, redis, one-to-many

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how I could convert this SQL database into a redis database. It is a one to many database consisting of keywords, responses, and a correlation table to link the two.

In the keywords table I have:

```
|ID---Keyword|
 1    This
 2    Cool
```

In the Responses table I have

```
|ID---Response|
 1    "I agree"
 2    "wow"
```

In the correlation table I have:

```
|ResponseID---KeywordID|
 1            1
 1            2
 2            2
```

To try to solve this in redis I've attempted to use plain strings to create a index of keyword id's to keywords:

```
set keyword:1 This
set keyword:2 Cool
```

Same with the responses:

```
set response:1 "I agree"
set response:2 "wow"
```

And then I used sets to join the two:

```
sadd keyword:1:response 1
sadd keyword:2:response 1
sadd keyword:2:response 2
```

Now the problem I am currently having is how to poll the data like how I would on a SQL database. I am not sure if this trouble is due to lack of information being added to the redis database or if I am just inexperienced.

Basically I want to obtain a group of keywords from my software, ex: "This", "Cool", and then do a lookup on their ID's (1 and 2 respectively). Then from their ID's use the correlation index to find the response ID, then use the response ID to get the response string. Due note that I need to have the data return responses that match the most keywords first, so if "This", "Cool" was given the response "I agree" would be presented, although if just the keyword "Cool" was given "wow" and "I agree" would be retrieved.

The purpose of this is so that when more keywords are specified, the more specific the response will become geared towards those keywords. The less keywords, the more likely it is to be a general response. This can be seen above as when two keywords were specified, there was only one response, where as when one keyword was specified there were two. **It will also be helpful if I could sort these results from most keywords matched to least keywords matched if possible.**

Is there something I am missing in regards to enough data inside the redis DB to make this happen? Or is this more going to be done in the client side application accessing the redis database.

I will be accessing the redis DB via ruby, but if this requires any code samples to be shown I can work with any language and port it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to have a keyword map to a redis set of responses.

```
keyword1 => { response1, response2 }
keyword2 => { response1, response 3 }
```

The process you laid out of getting the keywords from your software, response ids, then the response string is solved with this structure. When you add responses you will add them to the appropriate keywords.

You can get the number of responses in a set with SCARD. I personally don't see a simpler structure to give you the most keywords matched given a list of keywords.

One potentially useful improvement on using sets would be to have a list of responses so you could store a keyword mapt to a redis set of response ids. This would involve one extra step to use the response id to retrieve the actual response from redis.

```
keyword1 => { 0, 1 }
keyword2 => { 0, 2 }
responses => [ response1, response2, response3]
```

### Additional Thoughts

You also asked if there was enough data in the redis DB to make this happen. Given the above structure, the data is there, but you need to decide on how/where you want to calculate the counts of responses given a list of keywords. You could write a lua script to return a sorted list of most to least keywords matched that would be executed on the redis client. You could also receive the redis sets and calculate that information from ruby.

You should take a look at the redis doc for Sets:

[Redis Sets](https://redis.io/commands#set)

The command SINTER may come in handy if you want to find the overlap of responses between many keywords.

Update:

I think it would be easiest to put all of the responses in one large table in lua and then return the table of responses with their counts. E.x:

```
k1 => r1, r2, r3
k2 => r1, r2
k3 => r1, r3
```

In this case we would end up returning:

```
r1: 3
r2: 2
r3: 2
```

You could then use that table to determine how to proceed with your results. Some lua sudo code is below:

```
local allResponses = {}

-- go over the keys and add their responses to the global response table
for keyIndex, keyword in ipairs(KEYS) do
    local responses = redis.call('smembers', keyword);
    allResponses.add(responses)
end

local counts = {}
for responseIndex, response in ipairs(allResponses) do
    counts[response] = counts[response] + 1
end

return counts
```

Comment: Hi, could I get an example of a lua script that would return a sorted list of most to least keywords matched? At the moment SINTER suffices when I want to attempt to match all keywords given, but say if I supply 5 keywords, and I only need to return responses that match up to any 3 of them, I am not sure how I could do that. My goal in mind is that if for some reason 5 keywords used during SINTER fail to find a response I want to supply the same 5, but ask it for matches on any for 4, then 3, 2, 1, etc which will slowly broaden the search terms for a response. Thanks

Comment: I guess I could create an array of sets which rotate all keywords on the client side slowly decrementing in size and use SINTER to poll for responses and brute force it, but perhaps there is a feature or a better way to preform this.

Comment: You should be able to put the results from each keyword into one big list, then do a count for the number of times each response shows up. Something like counting sort could be great for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort.  I will see if I can write up a lua script later this evening that demonstrates this.